# How to perform brute force method with Knapsack /0-1 money-changing problem, with the following table of potential knapsack items

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, probability-or-statistics, evaluation

This is the listing item with 400 as Knapsack size...

```
items = Grid[{{"map", 9, 150}, {"compass", 13, 35}, {"water", 153, 
    200}, {"sandwich", 50, 160}, {"glucose", 15, 60}, {"tin", 68, 
    45}, {"banana", 27, 60}, {"apple", 39, 40}, {"cheese", 23, 
    30}, {"beer", 52, 10}, {"suntan cream", 11, 70}, {"camera", 32, 
    30}, {"T-shirt", 24, 15}, {"trousers", 48, 10}, {"umbrella", 73, 
    40}, {"waterproof trousers", 42, 70}, {"waterproof overclothes", 
    43, 75}, {"note-case", 22, 80}, {"sunglasses", 7, 20}, {"towel", 
    18, 12}, {"socks", 4, 50}, {"book", 30, 10}}, Frame -> All]
```

someone could help me? thanks in advance

Comment: This problem is underspecified - what is the knapsack size? And what's with the `Table` in your grid? That looks like a mistake. Also there's already a function for this: [`KnapsackSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KnapsackSolve.html) . It would also help if you could point out which number is the cost and which one is the payoff.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have added the listing in order to be more specified, the main purpose of this task is to solve it by using the brute force method algorithm with Mathematica, instead of using a function

Comment: Is this homework? It doesn't help that you made your data into an image that we can no longer copy - please keep the code in the question too, and show your best attempt so far.

Comment: Thanks for following up with me, yes it is homework, I have posted what I did so far, but my code doesn't return anything.
     bruteForce[items_] := Module[{n = 1},
     While[i = itemsIn; ++n;
      While[i > 1 && Mod[n, i--] == 0];
       i > 1];
    Return[items[[1 ;; 2]]]
   ]

Comment: What was that famous bit of movie advice? "Drop the trousers. Keep the umbrella"? "Drop the tin. Keep the banana"? My memory is so not there anymore.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau  May the Force be with you

Comment: It is May the Fourth so I guess I had that coming.